# Javascript: how to test an object is an object (and not an array or a string)?

Tags: javascript, collections

I know about (a instanceof Array) but how would I test for an object?

```
var c = {};

if ( c instanceof XXXX) {
   // should get thru
}

var s = "abscdef";

if ( s instanceof XXXX) {
   // should not get thru
}

var a = [];

if ( a instanceof XXXX) {
   // should not get thru
}
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly? {} is an object, not a collection.

Comment: Your terminology is confused - c is a `Object`, not a "collection".

Comment: Ok, sorry then. How to detect an object of any type then? (I edit the question)

Comment: Same way as array. if (c instanceof Object) ...

Comment: @Pilot It's about javascript, so I'd say no.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Looking at `Collection` as OP said I commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isObject(c) {
  return c instanceof Object 
    && !(c instanceof Array) 
    && !(c instanceof Function)
}
```

The `Array` and `Function` checks are necessary because JavaScript Arrays are also Objects (assuming that you don't want the function to return `true` for an Array or Function arguments)

Example output:

```
isObject([])
> false

isObject({})
> true

isObject(1)
> false

isObject('something')
> false

isObject(isObject)
> false
```

Comment: You can also add `&& !(c instanceof Function)` because `c = function(){}` is an instance of `Object` AND `Function`

Comment: Perfect, thanks @joews!: a fiddle to see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/43Jza/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is something like this? I'm sorry if I don't really understand the question.

```
function MyOwnType(name){
    this.name = name
}
var myInstance = new MyOwnType("StackOverflow");
console.log(myInstance instanceof(MyOwnType)) //this evaluates to true
console.log(myInstance instanceof(Array)) //this evaluates to false
```